# Atlassian Bitbucket access repo in project

Tags: git, bitbucket, bitbucket-server

My team is using Atlassian Bitbucket v7.2.3 (locally hosted).

We have multiple projects to help organize our repositories.

I ran into an odd workflow where the path for the remote (git remove -v) was different than what I would have thought.

I have two projects call them **Project1** and **Project2**. In Project1, I have a repo called **Repo1**.

Through a buggy script, I ended up cloning a Repo1 but referenced it through Project2.

For example, I ran...

```
git clone ssh://git@bitbucket.myorg.com:2222/Project2/Repo1.git
```

Bitbucket happily cloned Repo1 and shows the origin to be `ssh://git@bitbucket.myorg.com:2222/Project2/Repo1.git`.

Is Bitbucket doing some type of cross-project resolution of repositories?

I would have thought that the clone would have failed since I specified the wrong project.

Answer (score 0):

> Is Bitbucket doing some type of cross-project resolution of repositories?

No, it does not: double-check if you have a Repo1 in Project2 on your `bitbucket.myorg.com`
Meaning: Repo1 would be part of multiple projects, since a [BitBucket project is here to group repositories](https://confluence.atlassian.com/bitbucket/group-repositories-into-projects-792497956.html).